# BeautifulSoup Parses Table Incorrectly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

Having trouble getting Beautiful Soup to process a large table of play-by-play basketball data properly. Code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = urllib.request.Request('http://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/pbp/201611220LAL.html')
result = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
resulttext = result.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(resulttext, "html.parser")

pbpTable = soup.find('table', id="pbp")
```

If you run this example yourself, you will find that the table is not fully parsed- all we get out is this:

```
<table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table" data-cols-to-freeze="1" id="pbp">
<caption>Play-By-Play Table</caption>
<tr class="thead" id="q1">
<th colspan="6">1st Q</th></tr></table>
```

The problem is in the parsing itself printing the soup variable gives (among other things)

```
</div>
<div class="table_wrapper" id="all_pbp">
<div class="section_heading">
<span class="section_anchor" data-label="Play-By-Play" id="pbp_link"></span>
<h2>Play-By-Play</h2> <div class="section_heading_text">
<ul> <li>  Jump to: <a href="#q1">1st</a> | <a href="#q2">2nd</a> | <a href="#q3">3rd</a> | <a href="#q4">4th</a> <br> <span class="bbr-play-score key">scoring play</span> <span class="bbr-play-tie key">tie</span> <span class="bbr-play-leadchange key">lead change</span></br></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div> <div class="table_outer_container">
<div class="overthrow table_container" id="div_pbp">
<table class="suppress_all sortable stats_table" data-cols-to-freeze="1" id="pbp"><caption>Play-By-Play Table</caption><tr class="thead" id="q1">
<th colspan="6">1st Q</th></tr></table></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Most importantly, a /table tag appears out of nowhere. Viewing the page source of the relevant link we can see that the table is not closed there- it goes on for a while. Is there any fix for this besides implementing my own HTML parsing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"lxml"` or `"html5lib"` instead of `"html.parser"` in

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(resulttext, "lxml")`
```

and you get more data.

But you may have to install `lxml` or `html5lib` if you don't have yet.

```
pip install lxml

pip install html5lib
```

`lxml` may need C/C++ compiler, `libxml` library (`libxml.dll` on Windows), etc.

Comment: Thanks! html5lib worked for me, while I ran into "unable to find vcvarsall.bat" errors with lxml...and just realized you warned me about additional requirements. I'm good at reading!

Comment: BTW: see [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). There are precompiled modules for Python on Windows. There is `lxml`. But it still may need `libxml.dll`, `libxstl.dll`. Or check [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) - it installs Python and many [precompiled modules](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) - there is `lxml` too.